# Ctrl Char regex too restrictive

Tags: regex, char, ctrl

From another thread on this site I found this regex that I used to detect all ctrl chars for an AWS WAF rule:

```
(?i)0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F)
```

My issue is it's too restrictive; it blocked a URI that contains:

```
/...120x120.png
```

How can I tweak the regex to detect `0x12` but not `...120x120...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?i)(?<!\d)0x([01][0-9A-F]|7F)
    ^^^^^^^
```

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed on the left
- `0x` - a `0x` string
- `([01][0-9A-F]|7F)` - Group 1: `0` or `1` and then a hex char, or `7F`